# Is there a better way to join elements from three lists than a triple nested for loop?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have three lists like so:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
l3 = ['h', 'i', 'j']
```

Now, what I am trying to do is combine all the elements that are in the same position on one line like so:

```
line_1: 'adh'
line_2: 'bei'
line_3: 'cfj'
```

is there a better way to do this than a triple nested for loop?

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(len(l2)):
        for k in range(len(l3)):
            if i == j and j == k:
                print(l1[i] + l2[j] + l3[k])
```

Basically I am trying to get something running faster than O(n^3) because I have about 100,000 items I would like to do this with.

Not sure if there would be a way with the CSV module to do this but after the combining each row is going to be written to a csv file. I have not found what I am looking for thus far and figured someone out in the community might know how to better approach this.

Wow thanks everyone who took a look at this!. There were a couple answers and they all worked. I am going to mark the question answered for whoever posted first. Thanks again to everyone who took a look! I did not even know about the zip function.

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote those inner loops.

Comment: Look at builtin "zip" function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
l3 = ['h', 'i', 'j']

for line in (''.join(t) for t in zip(l1, l2, l3)):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```py
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
l3 = ['h', 'i', 'j']
for a,b,c in zip(l1, l2, l3):
   print(a, b, c)
```

But even the pattern you went with works fine if you cut the redundant recursion:

```py
for i in range(len(l1)):
   print(l1[i], l2[i], l3[i])
```

Edit: as noted in the other answer, you have to join them up again afterwards ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use only one loop, assuming that all lists have the same length:

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    print(l1[i]+l2[i]+l3[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

In one line, simplified by @juanpa.arrivillaga:

```
>>> list(map(''.join, zip(l1, l2, l3)))
['adh', 'bei', 'cfj']
```

OR, suggested by @2e0byo with a comprehension:

```
>>> ["".join(x) for x in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
['adh', 'bei', 'cfj']
```

Comment: or even: `["".join(x) for x in zip(l1, l2, l3)]`

Comment: don't get me wrong, making Guido squirm is part of the fun of functional programming ;)

Answer (score 0):

The join() string method returns a string by joining all the elements of an iterable. So easily get your output from the below code,

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
l3 = ['h', 'i', 'j']

line1="".join(l1)
line2="".join(l2)
line3="".join(l3)

print(f"line1-{line1}")
print(f"line2-{line2}")
print(f"line3-{line3}")
```